# Find current location like google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have one app that needs user's current location. In the application, I have registered two location providers to listen for location and additionally I have also checked for last known location too. But the app do not receive the location always. 
The surprising thing I found today is that,

GPS was off

but location from wireless network was on.

I opened google Maps and I can see that it is showing current location so accurately. But When I opened my app, it could not get location.

I was surprised seeing this and I think there is something google map is doing to receive location other than I have done.

Here is how I have registered for location

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = null;
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10, 100, this);

        Location location1 = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location1 != null)
            location = location1;
        Log.v(TAG, "Network listener Enabled");

    } catch (RuntimeException ee) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e(TAG, "Network Providers Disabled");

    }

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 100, this);

        Location location1 = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.v(TAG, "GPS listener enabled");
        if (location1 != null)
            location = location1;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GPS not available");

    }
```

I dont know if there are any other things that I need to do with. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I figuered that out also in my apps... but unfortunately we do not know their implementation ;). If you use the network provider, I think the whole initialisation process for retrieving location by network is done new. I am sure that GoogleMaps caches or is checking the location in a background service, so that you have instantly a location.

So you should do like a background service which is checking the location intervally and cache the location.

And by the way, thats the new way of location api out 2013: [location api new](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)